# Create new shapefile from Geometry generator

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I have a line shape and used QGIS geometry generator to modify the line. Now I would like to create a new shape file from the new style. Is that possible in QGIS?

I'm using QGIS 3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a treatment in the processing toolbox that should do the trick, it's called **geometry by expression**.

You just have to duplicate your expresion and then save the resulting file.

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly well